# Windows 7 restore - will it remove files in C:/myfolder?

Tags: windows, windows-7, system-restore

My Windows 7 laptop has developed a problem due to a driver. The laptop will not start (not even in safe mode) - it shows a blue screen and shuts off.

I've tried running StartupRepair which says it is unable to repair the computer and reports "Problem Signature 05: ExternalMedia / Problem Signature 07: BadDriver".

I am considering attempting to restore the computer to a previous restore point. However, I have some critical files in c:/myfolder (c:/xampp), which I cannot afford to lose.

Will the system restore exclude these files?

Comment: If you cannot lose them you will want to extract those files before you try anything. Besides any change using a system restore point wouldn't be permanent unless you confirmed it to keep the changes. **Its not guaranteed the files will be there so backup the files to an external drive before you try anything.** You can use a Live Linux Media to get this acomplished.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the sort of situation System Restore was created to resolve. There is absolutely nothing to worry about.

System Restore will not affect your files or folders, only the registry and Windows system files. It even describes the extent of the changes it makes before you run it.

There's a reason it is called *System* Restore.

But don't take my word for it:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/system-restore-frequently-asked-questions